# How do I connect to an IBM Mainframe?

Tags: gnome-terminal

How do I connect to a x3270 IBM Mainframe using the GNOME Terminal? I am not sure how to do this. Is there any documentation on it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [Telnet](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/telnet-ssl.1.html). Lucky for you there is a tool for this called  [x3270 - IBM host access tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/x3270.1x.html).

```
 x3270  opens  a  telnet  connection  to an IBM host in an X window.  It
       implements RFCs  2355  (TN3270E),  1576  (TN3270)  and  1646  (LU  name
       selection), and supports IND$FILE file transfer.  The window created by
       x3270 can use its own font for displaying characters, so it is a fairly
       accurate  representation  of  an  IBM  3278  or 3279.  It is similar to
       tn3270(1) except that it is X-based, not curses-based.

       The full syntax for host is:
              [prefix:]...[LUname@]hostname[:port]
```

Installation ([x3270 [image: Install x3270]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/x3270/)
)

```
sudo apt-get install x3270
```

According to the information in Ubuntu Software Center you will need to install the x3270 fonts manually since they are required ([xfonts-x3270-misc [image: Install x3270]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/xfonts-x3270-misc/)
):

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-x3270-misc
```

Answer (score 3):

Another tool that you can use is c3270.

c3270 opens a telnet connection to an IBM mainframe host in an Xterm window or Virtual Console. It can also connect to an IBM AS/400 as a 5250 terminal using the AS/400's 3270 emulation.

c3270 is similar to tn3270(1), and x3270(1) except that it is curses-based, not X-based.

c3270 implements RFCs 2355 (TN3270E), 1576 (TN3270), and 1646 (LU name selection), and supports IND$FILE file transfer.<sup>[UA](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/c3270/)</sup>

To install click [**c3270** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/c3270/)

Or, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install c3270
```

For the c3270 manual, see [here](http://x3270.bgp.nu/c3270-man.html)

Comment: Now for the 1m dollar question: what is better? ncurses or x-based :D

Comment: The Answer is: Its a matter of preference, I like ncurses better.  x3270 is also good.  +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your administrator.

But apart from any TN3270 terminal emulator, and you are not limited to OSS, there is FTP, SFTP, SSH, SCP, HTTP and a few other protocols.